# How do I run this macro for a specific worksheet, the workbook has many worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created several macro buttons on worksheet 5, this works if I'm on worksheet 1 but when I try to click the button for this macro on worksheet 5 it doesn't work. What do I need to add to make it select worksheet 1 if I'm on another worksheet in the same workbook?

```
Sub Delete_External ()
'
' Delete_External Macro

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Range("K1000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Range("K" & i) = "External" Then
            Range("K" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualify your objects with a worksheet.

```
Sub Delete_External ()
'
' Delete_External Macro

    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = ws.Range("K1000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Range("K" & i) = "External" Then
            ws.Range("K" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I would avoid deleting rows inside your loop as this can become time consuming depending on the data set and amount of criteria matches. Consider this alternative that loops through your range and creates a collection (`Union`) of cells that match your criteria. Once the loop is complete, delete the `Union` all at once.

This has also been updated to a more common last row finder methodology and removes the backwards loop since this method does not require it!

```
Sub Delete_External()
'
' Delete_External Macro

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    Dim DeleteMe As Range

    LR = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        If ws.Range("K" & i) = "External" Then
            If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("K" & i))
            Else
                Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("K" & i)
            End If  
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
        DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I got Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range and the following bit highlighted in yellow. : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emp List - Leavers")

Comment: That means the sheet doesn't exist. It needs to be character by character match.

Comment: I've copied the name exactly how it is and tried again but still the same error. I even tried renaming the sheet to "Sheet1" but it still didn't work. Any other ideas?